# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed parsing permissions Flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, windows-10, android-emulator, illegalstateexception

I am new to flutter. I have created a decent app that was working fine recently.(System info: VS code running in Windows 10)
While running the app with the emulator my laptop hung for a while couldn't get it to restart. So, I removed the battery and restarted the machine. After that nightmare began. Now if I run an application in debug mode for the emulator I am getting the below error. I tried reinstalling VS code. No use. Appreciate any advice.

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 64 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
E/AndroidRuntime(10192): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10192): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed parsing permissions file: /data/system/users/0/runtime-permissions.xml
E/AndroidRuntime(10192):    at com.android.server.pm.Settings$RuntimePermissionPersistence.readStateForUserSyncLPr(Settings.java:4702)
E/AndroidRuntime(10192):    at com.android.server.pm.Settings.readLPw(Settings.java:2737)
E/AndroidRuntime(10192):    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.(PackageManagerService.java:1909)
E/AndroidRuntime(10192):    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:1764)
E/AndroidRuntime(10192):    at com.android.server.SystemServer.startBootstrapServices(SystemServer.java:366)
E/AndroidRuntime(10192):    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:268)
E/AndroidRuntime(10192):    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:168)
E/AndroidRuntime(10192):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10192):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)